# "create new visual classes" button not clickable on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse, gwt-designer

I installed a new GUI designer software, and than restarted eclipse as requested but when eclipse reopened I couldn't click the "create new visual classes" button. it's clickable but it doesn't do anything. I have to click it in order to install the toolkit and to create a new jframe.

I downloaded the GUI designer from the following link:https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download

and I used the tutorial to install it in this link:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kSjGNcKYDI

my eclipse is Kepler version.

How can I finish installing the GUI designer (and use it)

Comment: Have you tried a complete uninstall/reinstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the GWT Designer included in the GPE is a slimmed down version that does not include things like creating UI classes from the Eclipse menus.

If you want this functionality, you need to install the full GWT Designer from here:

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.3

Note that I did just verify that this still allows opening the desired UI class creation wizards, but I have not verified that it works with GWT 2.6. I think that it should work in GWT 2.6.1 but cannot guarantee that. I've used it successfully with GWT 2.5.1.