# Google Eclipse designer button not responding

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse, gwt-designer

I have installed all the components of Google's plugin for Eclipse however the button that allows to create visual classes does not respond when I click on it.

[image]

Comment: Do you get any error message somewhere? Maybe in the Error view or Console view?

Comment: No, nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: Same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983481/create-new-visual-classes-button-not-clickable-on-eclipse). Unfortunately without an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the GWT Designer included in the GPE is a slimmed down version that does not include things like creating UI classes from the Eclipse menus.

If you want this functionality, you need to install the full GWT Designer from here:

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.3

Note that I did just verify that this still allows opening the desired UI class creation wizards, but I have not verified that it works with GWT 2.6. I think that it should work in GWT 2.6.1 but cannot guarantee that. I've used it successfully with GWT 2.5.1.

Note that your original title referred to Swing Designer. Swing Designer has never been a part of the Google Plugin for Eclipse. Google donated that product to the open-source community and it is now maintained by Eclipse. It is bundled with some versions of Eclipse as part of WindowBuilder. Their forum is here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/214/

You can get Swing Designer for Eclipse 4.3 from this update site:

Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler